# Default scheduling policy and priority of new QNX process/thread

Tags: multithreading, qnx, qnx-neutrino

The QNX documentation says a new thread inherits the scheduling policy and priority from the parent thread it was started from.

What if I start a new process from shell or from an init-script? Where does the scheduling policy and priority of the new process/thread come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **priority** of the new process will be set to `10`. This is described by QNX at the following [link](http://www.qnx.com/developers/articles/article_295_1.html):

> Under QNX Neutrino, processes will run at priority 10 by default.  So when you open a terminal and run a program, unless it takes steps to modify it's priority, it will be running at priority 10.

The **scheduling policy** instead will be set to the `Adaptive scheduling` until you will change it. I found this information in two different links ( [QNX doc](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/qnx_4.25_docs/qnx4/sysarch/microkernel.html) and [Tempus documentation](http://mazsola.iit.uni-miskolc.hu/tempus/parallel/doc/drotos/rtos/microkernel/schedul.html)). In particular the QNX documentation reports:

> Adaptive scheduling is the default scheduling method for programs created by the Shell.